# Trying to plot a quadratic regression, getting multiple lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making a demonstration of a different types of regression in numpy with ipython, and so far, I've been able to plot a simple linear regression without difficulty.  Now, when I go on to make a quadratic fit to my data and go to plot it, I don't get a quadratic curve but instead get many lines.  Here's the code I'm running that generates the problem:

```
import numpy
from numpy import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math

# Generate random data
X = random.random((100,1))
epsilon=random.randn(100,1)
f = 3+5*X+epsilon

# least squares system
A =numpy.array([numpy.ones((100,1)),X,X**2])
A = numpy.squeeze(A)
A = A.T
quadfit = numpy.linalg.solve(numpy.dot(A.transpose(),A),numpy.dot(A.transpose(),f))

# plot the data and the fitted parabola
qdbeta0,qdbeta1,qdbeta2 = quadfit[0][0],quadfit[1][0],quadfit[2][0]
plt.scatter(X,f)
plt.plot(X,qdbeta0+qdbeta1*X+qdbeta2*X**2)
plt.show()
```

What I get is this picture (zoomed in to show the problem):
[image]

You can see that rather than having a single parabola that fits the data, I have a huge number of individual lines doing something that I'm not sure of.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to make `X` be a 1D array, not a 100x1 2D array.

Comment: @BrenBarn If I do squeeze to X everywhere, I get a (100,) array, but now get dozens of parabolas fitting my data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `X` is ordered randomly, so it's not a good set of x values to use to draw one continuous line, because it has to double back on itself.  You could sort it, I guess, but TBH I'd just make a new array of x coordinates and use those:

```
plt.scatter(X,f)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
plt.plot(x,qdbeta0+qdbeta1*x+qdbeta2*x**2)
```

gives me
[image: example plot]

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much!  That was a noob mistake on my part.

Comment: @Matt: incidentally, is there a reason you're doing this manually?  `np.polyfit(X.squeeze(), f.squeeze(), 2)` gives you your three coefficients in a much simpler fashion.

Comment: Yes, two reasons. One, I didn't know about polyfit. Two, I'm coding the math that I have written down, so I'm writing my python to reflect the normal equations so that the connection is clear.